# WP: adding Javascript to specific woo commerce pages

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm developing an eCommerce site using Woo-Commerce, i'm hoping to introduce some JavaScript to my sale pages only, in the name of a finance slider. What is the best way to go about including a specific piece of JavaScript on my Woo-Commerce sale page only.

I'm new to WP so apologies if this is obvious, google didn't help though. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add inline javascripts or add then in `<head>` using <script> tag?

Comment: Preferably in the head linking to an external script. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your themes functions.php.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts' );

function my_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( is_page('your-specific-page') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'script-name',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js',
            array( 'jquery' )
        );
    }
}
```

Documentation for [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `is_page()` conditional function.

```
function wpse208799_add_js_to_specific_pages(){

    if ( is_page( '10' ) ) { // Change the page ID
        wp_register_script( 
            'handle',
            'http://urltothescript',
            array('jquery'),
            '1.0'
        );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'handle' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse208799_add_js_to_specific_pages' );
```